# How to perform below operation in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, error-correction, quantum-operation, density-matrix, error-mitigation

I want to implement the below equation in Qiskit.

$(A \otimes B).\rho.(B^\dagger \otimes A^\dagger)$ where $\rho$ is a density matrix and $A$ and $B$ are CNOT gates.
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}. $$
The final $pf$ I got using the codes below is an operator, not a density matrix, as **$dot()$ returns an operator**. Hence, I can not use $\texttt{state_fidelity()}$ on it. **The dimension of $\rho$ is 16**. I can not use $evolve()$ since it is **not** any normal operator usage. Please let me know if there is any other method I can implement the above operation. I will be grateful.

```
p1=[[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0]]        
p2=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]        
pa1=qi.Operator(p1)     
pa2=qi.Operator(p2)         
pa3=(pa2.transpose()).tensor(pa1.transpose())
pf=((pa1.tensor(pa2)).dot(rho)).dot(pa3)
```

where qi is :

```
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Qiskit's `DensityMatrix` class accepts any object with a `to_matrix()` method. And since `Operator` class has a [`to_matrix()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.to_matrix.html), you can simply convert `pf` to a `DensityMatrix` that can be used with `state_fidelity()`:

```
F = state_fidelity(qi.DensityMatrix(pf), rho2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but issue still persists.

Comment: I ran the code on my machine without issue. Could you add more details to your question? For example: what version of Qiskit you are running? And what is the exact error messages (if any)?